# JNI and Java have different results when calling Integer.valueOf(int),is it a bug?

Tags: java, integer, java-native-interface

Eclipse

```
Integer v1 = Integer.valueOf(55);
Integer v2 = Integer.valueOf(55);
System.out.println("v1==v2 ? " + (v1 == v2));
//bacause of Integer cache, v1 == v2 is true
```

Visual Studio

```
jclass Integer = jni_env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
jmethodID valueOf = jni_env->GetStaticMethodID(Integer, valueOf", "(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;");
jint intV = 55;
jobject v1= jni_env->CallStaticObjectMethod(Integer, valueOf, intV);
jobject v2 = jni_env->CallStaticObjectMethod(Integer, valueOf, intV);
```

v1 = 0x0000000019b01000 {...}

v2 = 0x0000000019b01008 {...}

Obviously, v1 and v2 are not the same object.Can someone tell me why?Thanks

Comment: the version is JDK1.8.0_144

Comment: What exactly are you printing to get those values of v1 and v2? Could these just be the addresses on the stack of those two variables? (I appreciate I could be displaying an horrific ignorance of JNI types...)

Comment: Yes, `jobject` is an opaque pointer to `struct _jobject`. You can see that by reading `jni.h`.

Comment: Maybe I find the reason. As @KarelG says, In vs, v1 and v2 are just jni objs,the internal object are the same. `*(unsigned long*)0x0000000019d0b660` and `*(unsigned long*)0x0000000019d0b668` has the same value 0x802a2bf8,it prove that

Comment: Nothing obvious about it. Where exactly does it say that two different `jobjects` referring to the same underlying Java object should have the same value?

Comment: JNI does not define `bool operator==(const jobject a, const jobject b)`. So, what are you intending on comparing?

Answer (score 1):

When using `Integer.valueOf()` method in Java, you are creating an instance of Integer which is a wrapper around a primitive type: `int`.

You are already aware that the above method caches values. If you check the documentation, you can find

> Returns an Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as **this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values**. This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range. [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int))

Therefore

```
Integer v1 = Integer.valueOf(55);
Integer v2 = Integer.valueOf(55);
System.out.println("v1==v2 ? " + (v1 == v2));
```

will evaluate as true. But here, the operation done with `==` is not on the *value* itself, but the *reference* to the object in the heap memory. Since `.valueOf()` caches 55 automatically, v1 and v2 points to the same object.

When using jni with the following call

```
jobject v1= jni_env->CallStaticObjectMethod(Integer, valueOf, intV);
```

then `v1` is a jni object that wraps around the java object. If you do the same call for `v2`, you get a different jni object. Both object have different references but will point to the same integer object internally. That's what you see.